# How to retrieve specific values from an array of string in RDD spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have the data:

```
{CurrentDate:05.24.2008,Employeeid:90786532432,Division:TX_VG}
{Division:NW_VG,CurrentDate:01.18.2006,Employeeid:907806532432}
```

as a string array in RDD. How can I retrieve only `Employeeid` and `Division` from this string array? I have two sets of strings. The data in the strings will not be in the same order always

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It's working fine..

Comment: I am getting complilation error when I integrate this code with main code. Value of index of slice is not a member of Option[string].

Comment: Good question I will say, informative for others I think!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq("{CurrentDate:05.24.2008,Employeeid:90786532432,Division:TX_VG}", 
                             "{Division:NW_VG,CurrentDate:01.18.2006,Employeeid:907806532432}"))

val rdd2 = rdd.map(x => (x.slice  
                      (x.indexOfSlice("Division:")+9, 
                       (x.indexOfSlice("}", (x.indexOfSlice("Division:")+9))) min 
                       (    if   (  x.indexOfSlice(",", (x.indexOfSlice("Division:")+9)) == -1) {1000000} else {x.indexOfSlice(",", (x.indexOfSlice("Division:")+9)) } )
                      )
                        ,
                     x.slice
                       (x.indexOfSlice("Employeeid:")+11, 
                       (x.indexOfSlice("}", (x.indexOfSlice("Employeeid:")+11))) min 
                       (    if   (  x.indexOfSlice(",", (x.indexOfSlice("Employeeid:")+11)) == -1) {1000000} else {x.indexOfSlice(",", (x.indexOfSlice("Employeeid:")+11)) } )
                      )

                    )
              )
rdd2.collect
```

returns:

```
res52: Array[(String, String)] = Array((TX_VG,90786532432), (NW_VG,907806532432))
```